# How to update starred value of contact in android?

Tags: android

In android, I want to make existing contact favorite from application. I am using `getContentResolver.update()` method for this. No exception is thrown, but when i check the contacts they are not updated. I tried all the solutions mentioned but somehow it is not working. Please can someone give me an exact solution for this.

Comment: Are you sure you update [Starred](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#STARRED) field with value 1 ?

Comment: 0 is for not starred, 1 is for starred.

Comment: Yeah this is what I have done : cv.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED, 1);

and then used
 getContentResolver().update(updateUri, cv, where, whereArgs);

Comment: May be the where condition doesn't match. Run a `query()` using same `where,whereArgs` see if received cursor has any rows.

Comment: hey thanks.I will check the query once again..